# Area of ascending regions on implicit plot - $\cos(y^y) = \sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, area

Take the equation

$$ \cos \left( y^y \right) = \sin(x) $$

The plot forms a kind of skew checkerboard, where each "tile" shrinks as $y$ increases. I was attempting to find the sum of the areas (the blue regions in the image below), but cannot find an expression for each area. I would like to find an expression where $a_n$ is the $n$-th region up and show whether $\sum a_n$ diverges or converges and if so the value of the sum.

[image: plot image]

I'm not entirely sure how to find the corners of the region algebraically, but the first one has approximate corners: left- $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},2.47 \right)$, top- $ \left(\frac{\pi}{2},2.62 \right)$, right- $ \left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2.47 \right)$, bottom- $ \left(\frac{\pi}{2},2.26 \right)$. If we approximate the shape of the first region as a rhombus, we get $$A \approx \frac{(3\pi/2 + \pi/2) (2.62 - 2.26)}{2} = 1.130973 \text{ or } a_0 \approx 1.130973.$$

Comment: In terms of the Lambert W function:$$y=\frac{\ln\left(\pm x+\frac{2\pi n+1}2\right)}{W\left(\ln\left(\pm x\frac{2\pi n+1}2\right)\right)}$$

Comment: this answer gives only a formula and no plan to solve the problem

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm not sure how to use this to find the intersection points or the areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is only a partial answer.

The area of the region you are referring to is
$$
A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}}\left[\left(\frac{3\pi}2-\arcsin\cos(y^y)\right)-\left(\frac{\pi}2+\arcsin\cos(y^y)\right)\right]\text{d} y
$$
where $y_n$ is the sequence of successive points where the function $\arcsin\cos(y^y)$ is not differentiable (we will determine these later). The way we have obtained this integral is by noting that the eqaution $\cos(y^y) = \sin(x)$ is a periodic continuation of the equation $x=\arcsin(\cos(y^y))$ (and its reflection across the line $x=\pi/2$), with period $\pi$.

**Note:** You can see this by going ahead and graphing the above function of $y$ next to your graph of the implicit equation above.

**EDIT:** I can't believe I missed it but I just realized that the sum simplifies to $\int_{y_1}^\infty$ of the function. You can skip some of the sections below about $y_n$ if you prefer.

Let $f(y) = \arcsin(cos(y^y))$. The reason we're integrating over $[3\pi/2-f(y)] - [\pi/2+f(y)]$ as opposed to simply $[\pi-f(y)]-f(y)$ is because $f(y)$ is negative, with minimum value $\pi/2$, so we shift everything up to make the area positive.

Let $I_n$ denote the integral in the summand above. Then
$$
I_n = \int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}}(\pi - 2f(y))\text{d} y = \pi(y_{n+1}-y_n)-2\int_{y_n}^{y_{n+1}}f(y)\text{d} y
$$

Wolfram Alpha gives no closed form for the indefinite integral of $f(y)$ in terms of elementary functions (or transcendental/special ones for that matter), so it may be of use to us to know what exactly the $y_n$ are.

What exactly is happening at the points where $f(y)$ is not differentiable? These are the points where $\cos(y^y)$ reaches a critical point, and then goes in the opposite direction. Another way of seeing this is noting that $\arcsin\cos x$ is a transformation of the [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave), which has inflection points at the critical points of $\cos x$.

Hence, are points $y_n$ are the critical points of $\cos(y^y)$. The derivative of $\cos(y^y)$ is
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\cos(y^y) = -y^y(\ln(y)+1)\sin(y^y)
$$
Setting this equal to zero gives $y_1 = \frac1e$ (which gives $\ln(y)=-1$), and $y_n = \exp(\text{W}(\ln(\pi n)))$ for $n>1$ (where $\text{W}(x)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)).

Consider $n>1$. Then
$$
I_n = \int_{e^{\text{W}(\ln(\pi n))}}^{e^{\text{W}(\ln(\pi(n+1)))}}\arcsin(\cos(x^x))\text{d}x
$$
We can make the substitution $u=x^x$ by noting that $x = \text{W}(\ln u)$, and so $\text{d}u = x^x(\ln x + 1)\text{d} x = u(\text{W}(\ln u) + 1)\text{d}x$, which gives
$$
I_n = \int_{\pi n}^{\pi (n+1)}\frac{\arcsin(\cos u)}{\text{W}(\ln u) + 1}\frac{\text{d}u}{u}
$$

This is where I've run out of time, and partially out of ideas. I don't see any simple route to take to evaluate this integral, and I haven't taken a good look at its asymptotics to determine if the sum will even converge. I hope this has at least shed some light on an approach to the problem.

**EDIT:** I realized that I might've been overcomplicating things by introducing $y_n$, and not noting that since the integrals in the summand have consecutive start and end points, we can write the area as
$$
\begin{aligned}
A & = \int_{y_1}^\infty(\pi-2f(y))\text{d}y \\
& = \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\pi\left(N-\frac1e\right)-2\int_{e^{-1/e}}^{N^N}\frac{\arcsin(\cos(u))}{\text{W}(\ln u)+1}\frac{\text{d}u}{u}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

I haven't looked much into this limit yet.

Comment: One may note $\arcsin(\cos(\theta))$ simplifies.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Good point, and that would get rid of the $u$ in the denominator of the last integral (over differentiable intervals of the triangle wave). Then maybe one could expand the denominator with the Lambert W function as a power series or Fourier series?

Comment: Thanks, great work! Might I add that mathematica was incapable of numeric integration or limit calculation due to precision and rapid oscillation.

Comment: @Dando18 I've found that, by making the substitution SimplyBeautifulArt suggests, you can reduce it to a (rather ugly) sum of the integrals
$$
\int\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{W}(\ln u)+1},\qquad\int\frac{1}{\text{W}(\ln u)+1}\frac{\text{d}u}u
$$
Over intervals of length $\pi$. I might write up something about it later.

Comment: Where does the $N^N$ endpoint of integration come from? I feel like I'm missing something in the last step of your edit.

Comment: @Dando18 from making the subsitution $u = x^x$.

Comment: I see now. I'm still curious about the result of this limit, but I'll mark the answer as correct. Great answer!

Comment: @Dando18 Here is the expansion I mentioned above, assuming $M^M = 2\pi N$ for $N\in\mathbb{N}$ (it'll be in the next comment because it's too big):

Comment: $$
\int_{e^{-1/e}}^{M^M}\frac{\arcsin(\cos u)}{\text{W}(\ln u) + 1}\frac{\text{d} u}{u} = \int_{e^{-1/e}}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi/2-u}{\text{W}(\ln u) + 1}\frac{\text{d}u}{u} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac\pi2+2\pi n\right)\int_{2\pi n}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\text{d}u}{u(\text{W}(\ln u)+1)} - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\int_{2\pi n}^{(2n+1)\pi}\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{W}(\ln u)+1} + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\int_{(2n+1)\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{W}(\ln u)+1} - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{3\pi}2+2\pi n\right)\int_{(2n+1)\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\frac{\text{d}u}{u(\text{W}(\ln u)+1)}
$$

Comment: That's it in its rawest form. There are clearly ways of cleaning it up (one popular but abusive form I've seen is writing $A\int_a^b f + B\int_c^d f = (A\int_a^b + B\int_c^d)f$), but the heart of the matter is the two integrals above. I'm not familiar enough with residue theory to know if there's a complex analysis way of solving these integrals, but it seems like a reasonable next step to attempt.